# Definition of C$^\ast$-algebra: which conditions can be deduced from the others?

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, involutions

A C$^\ast$-algebra is a Banach algebra $A$ with an involution, i.e. a map $\ast$ such that:

1. $(x^\ast)^\ast=x$ for all $x\in A$;
2. $(x+y)^\ast=x^\ast+y^\ast$ for all $x,y\in A$;
3. $(ax)^\ast=\overline ax^\ast$, for all $x\in A,a\in\mathbb{C}$;
4. $\|xx^\ast\|=\|x\|^2$, for all $x\in A$.

I know 1-2-3 do not imply 4 (counterexample: $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with convolution and $f^\ast(x)=\overline{f(-x)}$ and $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ with convolution and $f^\ast(k)=\overline{f(-k)}$, and also Wiener algebra with whatever matches the involution on $\ell^1$ via the algebra isomorphism sending an element of Wiener into its FOurier transform in $\ell^1$, conjugation perhaps?), but is there any of 1-2-3 that can be deduced by the other conditions? Or more explicitly:

1. Can 1 be deduced from 2-3-4?
2. Can 2 be deduced from 1-3-4?
3. Can 3 be deduced from 1-2-4?

And how is any of the above 3 implications proven/disproven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of $C^*$-algebra is missing the property $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$. Without that requirement, a more natural (to me) example where 1-2-3 are true and 4 is false is to take $M_2(\mathbb C)$ and define the adjoint as conjugation entrywise.

1. Condition 1 cannot be deduced from 2-3-4. For example, let $A=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, and let $$x^*=(\overline{\gamma(x)},\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2},\ldots),$$ where $\gamma$ is any state.
2. I don't think that condition 2 can be deduced from 1-3-4. But I cannot think of an example right now.
3. Condition 3 cannot be deduced from 1-2-4. For example, take $A=\mathbb C$, and the identity as involution.

Comment: Whoops! I forgot about that requirement. I guess that doesn't help with 3, right? So condition 3 cannot be deduced from 1-2-4 and the missing condition, same counterexample, right? What is a "state"? And can the missing requirement be deduced from 1-2-3-4?

Comment: What norm and product were you considering on $M_2(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: Yes, the example for condition 3 still works with the product condition. A state is a positive functional of norm one. I cannot think quickly of an example where 1-2-3-4 hold but the product rule fails; that said, I don't usually spend time construction weird involutions to see what happens. And I would be really surprised if any of the 5 conditions follows from the others.

Comment: On $M_2(\mathbb C)$, the usual product and the operator norm.

Comment: I gues example 1 had entrywise producr on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, right? Then the product rule holds, which shows 2-3-4-product do not imply 1.

Comment: Not with "any state ", but yes if we use a character.

Comment: what is a character?

Comment: A nonzero multiplicative state. If you want to think about C $^*$-algebras at  all, you will have to read the basics.

Comment: We just called them "multiplicative functionals", I guess, @Martin. The spectrum of an element is the set of the images of that element via characters, isn't it? In the commutative case at least.

Comment: @MickG: I wrote it that way because it is not immediately obvious to me that a multiplicative functional is positive (i.e., preserves adjoints).As yo say, in the commutative case (only) the spectrum is image through the characters; that's basic Banach-algebra theory.